# How to call a single mail function that will take from,to,content of the mail,subject and data that we want to pass?

Tags: php, laravel

i am thinking to create a single mail function in Laravel that will take from,from name,to,toname,content of the mail,data that we want to pass to the mail and subject.i want to call this function everytime i need to send a mail by just passing the above mentioned parameters .i want to create the view of the mail dynamically .i just want to call that function everytime is need to send mail.How do i do that by using helper function or by creating a console command.please give some suggestion in Laravel??

Comment: Can you be more specific/concrete about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more Laravel way of handling this is laravel notifications.

Laravel notifications got a perfect support for mail notifications, where you can do message formatting, customising recipients and templates.

Link to latest documentation cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be small nice if you a make a custom class for sending emails from your project and the reuse-ability of the class help you to write less code.

if you want any more suggestion or instance for class let me know please.

Comment: Yes, i am using my custom class for the entire project.

Comment: Sorry for the late response i am little busy.. hope you have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
// 1- Define your variables
$params = [
    'from'      => 'from@example.com',
    'fromTitle' => 'Example',
    'subject'   => 'subject example',
    'to'        => 'test@gmail.com',
];

$content = [
    'title'   => 'Title',
    'content' => 'lorem ipsuim',
];

// 2- Create a function 
public function sendMail(array $params, array $content){
    Mail::send('mails.name_of_blade', $content, function ($message) use ($params) {
        $message->from($params['from'], $params['fromTitle']);
        $message->subject($params['subject']);
        $message->to($params['to']);
    });
    return true;
}
```

And then create a new blade file and put it in the mails folder under the view folder and choose a name for this file, in this case i use `name_of_blade`.